# My JavaScript code is not working when running with Flask

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, flask

This is my HTML code, which includes the JavaScript code as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />      
      <title>Image Colorizer</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="thisContent">

       <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <br>
                <br>

            <center>
                <label for="link" class="stext">URL Image</label>
                <br>
                <br>

                <input type="text" id="link" name="link" placeholder="url here..." class="inp">

                <br>
                <br>
                <h1>OR</h1>
                <br>
                <br>

                <div class="local">
                    <label for="file" class="sitext">Choose Local Image</label>
                    <input type="file" id='file' name="file" hidden>
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="submitbtn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="myBtn">
                        <span class="submitbtn-text">Colorize</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </center>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="cat">
            <div class="cat__body"></div>
            <div class="cat__body"></div>
            <div class="cat__tail"></div>
            <div class="cat__head"></div>
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>

    </div>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");


            // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
            btn.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "block";
            }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code works perfectly when I normally run it on the browser without flask, but as soon as I run it with flask, the js code has not effect. The only change I have made is loading the css file with flask jinja command but it also loading without a problem.

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console? You can try `console.log("testing")` to see if code is really executed and see if it is logged in browser console.

Comment: ok, I'll try and see. Thank You

Comment: yes, I added console.log("testing") inside btn.onclick function and it executes

Comment: @mr.txnh it seems to me that the modal shouldn't be even hidden in the first place, does the modal class have any css stuff? bg color or sth?

Comment: @Matiiss here is my css code : https://pastebin.com/pKFaqsxC, please can you take a look on it, the modal classes and all are at the bottom.

Comment: @mr.txnh the official answer is "I have no idea" yet at least

Comment: Is the model hidden already and when you click the button the model is still hidden? Am I right? Can you try using `modal.style.display = "block !important";`

Comment: first of I don't know javascript but from python perspective You would be just changing a variable but would that be updated by browser? also I will try look at some bootstrap code and then come back

Comment: @Matiiss ok, I will try to find something

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you, I found what happened instead of modal.style.display = "block !important"; I jus need to do modal.style.display = "flex !important";. Sorry to make you trouble

Comment: @charchit Thank you, I found what happened instead of modal.style.display = "block !important"; I jus need to do modal.style.display = "flex !important";. Sorry to make you trouble

Comment: @mr.txnh it would be great if you added that as an answer to your question since it may be helpful for others in the future